# Change color of a button if selected or hovered

Tags: python, gtk3, pygtk

Since I usually have a lot windows open in several desktops I built this script to help me switch to a certain app faster: [**Code Here**](https://bitbucket.org/ljpr-personal/windowswitch/src/master/windowSwitch.py)

For increased convenience I added a keyboard shortcut to execute the script.

While I don't think it's that bad for a newbie, in my desktop theme the button selection is very subtle:
[This is how it looks to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZVhB.png)

I'd like to have a lot more emphasis on the selected button by changing it's color. That would certainly help me switch between apps even faster. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use [gtk-inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector) to experiment styling your application with [GTK+ CSS](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html). Once this is done, you can code the changes in the app, using GtkCssProvider. See https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html . Can't say much more, I never did theming.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize it by [using CSS](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html).

You could experiment in various ways. For example, I usually modify `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and use `gtk3-demo` as sample application:

```
button:hover {
  background: #FF0;
}
button:active {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #F00;
}
```

[image]
Once you have it, you should restrict the styling to your own buttons by e.g. applying a [custom class](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-add-class) and using it in your CSS selectors:

```
button.mycustomclass:hover {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I think I can achieve what I want now.